# Сохранение строчки во временную переменную mysql

Tags: mysql

Например, у меня есть запрос:

```
SELECT id, subid, alias
FROM table
WHERE id IN ( 2, 8, 4, 7 )
ORDER by id
```

Мне нужно получать каждую найденную строчку и сохранять во временную переменную, чтобы сравнивать со следующей найденной строчкой выборки типа `@result = IF( @old.subid == @new.id , true, false)`. Как это реализовать в запросе mysql?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id, subid, alias,
       @result:=IF(subid=@oldid, true, false),
       @oldid:=id
  FROM table,
       (select @oldid:=0,@result:=NULL) A
 WHERE id IN ( 2, 8, 4, 7 )
 ORDER by id
```

В подзапросе во `from` необходима инициализация начальными значениями. В списке выборки основного запроса запоминание `oldid` должно выполнятся после работы с этим значением из предыдущей записи, т.е. в конце списка выводимых значений.

Comment: подзапросу alias надо бы

Comment: @splash58 Точно, забыл

Comment: Блин не работает....

Comment: @modelfak Что значит "не работает" что оно не делает и что делает вместо этого

Comment: @Mike oldid - всегда равен ид текущей записи, а не предыдущей. Я так понял невозможно обратится к предыдущей записи в выборке.

Comment: @modelfak Да нет, именно так к предыдущей и обращаются. Вы сделайте `select id, @oldid, @oldid:=id from ...` и увидите, что @oldid во второй колонке - старое значение, в третьей - уже новое, потому как его присвоили в ней. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95ca7f/1