# Переход от таблицы типа SCD1 к типу SCD2 в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица типа SCD1. В такой таблице хранится дата начала использования тарифа (start_date) для каждого клиента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно написать запроc, чтобы прийти к типу SCD2. А в такой таблице будет храниться уже дата начала и конца использования тарифа (finish_date).
Результат должен быть такой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные SCD2 напрямую получаются из SCD1. Например для клиента №1 указаны три даты в колонке start_date. Это значит, что с 10.09 он начал пользоваться тарифом (rate) №1, 12.09 перешел на тариф №2, а 17.09 перешел обратно на тариф №1. Таким образом, он пользовался тарифом №1 с 10.09 по 12.09, тарифом №2 с 12.09 по 17.09, а затем опять тарифом №1.

Comment: Что ты хотел в итоге спросить? как построить структуру второй таблицы? выполнив CREATE TABLE?

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов нужно написать запрос в общем случае, чтобы получить вторую таблицу из первой, а не просто вручную вбить данные в новую таблицу.

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов т.е. написать код, чтобы перейти от scd1 к scd2

Comment: не понятно каким образом 19.09 из первой таблицы превратилось в 17.09 во второй. А так то, если вам надо поставить во вторую колонку следующую дату с тем же client вам надо использовать функцию lead(start_date) over(partition by client order by start_date) если у вас 8 MySQL или воспользоваться запоминанием в переменной предыдущей даты (со сбросом в null при смене client) при сортировке в обратном порядке, если более ранняя версия. что то из этой серии https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522037/194569

Comment: Вопрос ты как то задал понятный лишь тебе. Тебе нужно произвести миграцию данных, из одного типа таблицы, в таблицу с другим типом. Судя из твоих комендантов. Но в другой таблице появляется поле finish_date. Разъясни по какому алгоритму или откуда там появились данные? Может тогда кто то тебе и поможет. А так эти данные лишь у тебя в голове.

Comment: @Mike исправил ваше замечание.

Comment: @АндрейСолуянов добавил описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой запрос помог решить проблему. Таблица SCD1 немного была изменена, но суть все та же