# Как убрать первые строки для каждой группы (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица с данными клиентов (клиент, тариф и дата начала использования тарифа).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно написать запрос (СУБД mysql), чтобы исключить первые строки для каждого клиента.

Результат должен выглядеть так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно с помощью коррелированного подзапроса выбрать:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl AS t
WHERE `date`>(
     SELECT MIN(i.`date`) FROM tbl AS i 
     WHERE i.client = t.client
     GROUP BY i.`client`
);
```

Или с помощью `JOIN`'а:

```
SELECT t.* FROM tbl AS t
JOIN (SELECT client, MIN(`date`) AS m_date FROM tbl GROUP BY client) AS m
  ON t.client=m.client
WHERE t.`date`>m_date;
```

По идее оба варианта должны быть одинаковы по сложности, но для уверенности лучше сверится с планом. Возможно, есть какой-то более оптимальный способ, но что-то мне на ум пока ничего не приходит.

Comment: Если честно, я пытаюсь решить вот эту задачу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160792/Переход-от-таблицы-типа-scd1-к-типу-scd2-в-mysql?noredirect=1#comment2013311_1160792 без использования функции lead(). Может у Вас есть идеи, как ее можно решить, используя примитивы JOIN и GROUP BY

Comment: @maxdembovsky, когда-то я такое делал ещё на 5.6, так что без оконных функций, но помню, что получалось это через одно место: громоздко и медленно... так что пришлось в итоге заводить отдельную таблицу для интервалов и поддерживать её триггерами... как именно это получилось я стараюсь не вспоминать... ЗЫ: не стоит вставлять скрины там, где уместен текст...